# How many ratings are enough to display an average for an app on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have seen the message

"We have not received enough ratings to display an average for the current version of this application"

How many ratings are enough to warrant a display?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/off-topic/30721-1st-app-customer-ratings.html), about 5.

Answer (score 9):

Must be more than 5. I've got 7 and still have no average.

Update: Looks like it's 10 reviews needed now...

Update 2: Hmmm, also looks like a free app got an average with just over 5 ratings. I wonder if there's a different average needed depending on the payment scale

Comment: Bear in mind the link is two years old, and this question is a year old. Things change.

Comment: Ok,  in my experience, it looks like as of Fall 2011 an app requires 10 reviews to display an average.

Comment: @JustinMilo What was your pricing model for the app when you said its 10 reviews ?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, it is not that number either.  We have over 25 reviews on our app since the update and it is now six days and it still says "Not enough reviews".  Not sure what is the situation.